# Mule iterate over xpath result

Tags: java, xpath, mule

I've set the following xml as `payload` in order to iterate over every product using `splitter` component.

```
<root>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>apple</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>orange</name>
    </product>
</root>

<splitter expression="#[xpath('//product')]" />
```

The `splitter` component returns an object of type `org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement` on which I call the method `asXML()` to get single product's xml.

First iteration

```
<product>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>apple</name>
</product>
```

Second iteration

```
<product>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>orange</name>
</product>
```

---

I need to replace `splitter` with `foreach` component, but I'm having some troubles.

```
<foreach collection="#[xpath('//product')]">
    ...
</foreach>
```

The `foreach` component returns an object of type `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl` which hasn't the method `asXML()`.
Any idea how I can get products'xml as `String` as explained in the first example?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: are the types castable somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Mule's `dom-to-xml-transformer`.

Reference: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/DomToXml+Transformer